# Soundcloud - searching for more than term?

Tags: api, search, soundcloud

How do you do an OR search for multiple terms with the Soundcloud API?

Separating by comma seems to do an AND search:

e.g.

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=CLIENTKEY&q=chicago,parks&limit=50

On Google API you can use %7C to do an OR search but that doesn't seem to work with Soundcloud?

e.g. http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=CLIENTKEY&q=chicago%7Cparks&limit=50

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Currently it is not possible to do "OR" queries against the `/tracks` resource.

Our proposed solution is to do two request and combine the results and remove any duplicates.

`http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=CLIENTKEY&q=chicago&limit=50`

`http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=CLIENTKEY&q=parks&limit=50`

The combined result will of course not be ordered by the combined relevance of the two search terms, though you could take the duplicates and move them "on top" of the rest.

HTH
Hannes